# VueJS dynamic load remote JS file

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a VueJS application that references a remote JS file provided by a vendor. I've got a development/staging environment and a separate production environment. The vendor has given me 2 URLs to the necessary JS file, one URL for production and one for test/staging. My question is, I want to load the JS file in the Vue component that needs it but have the URL be different based on what environment I'm in. I'm only wanting to load the JS files if the application is deployed inside an iframe. Something like the following:

```
created () {
    // only load the JS file if we are deployed in an iframe
    if (window !== window.top) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            // load http://vendor.url/production/file.js
        } else {
            // load http://vendor.url/staging/file.js
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. I'd like to do this in the most secure manner possible.